# Error Implementing a a JFrame in Netbeans GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am implementing a Sniffer using Jpcap in Netbeans.
The code is given below.
It works fine in the terminal and gives me the correct output.

Now when i try to develop a gui to selecte the network interface and show the captured packets in a table the problem arises.

```
import jpcap.*;
import jpcap.NetworkInterface;

import jpcap.packet.DatalinkPacket;
import jpcap.packet.EthernetPacket;
import jpcap.packet.ICMPPacket;
import jpcap.packet.IPPacket;
import jpcap.packet.Packet;
import jpcap.packet.TCPPacket;
import jpcap.packet.UDPPacket;

class Te implements PacketReceiver {

    static int i = 0;
    String protocoll[] = {"HOPOPT", "ICMP", "IGMP", "GGP", "IPV4", "ST", "TCP", "CBT", "EGP", "IGP", "BBN", "NV2", "PUP", "ARGUS", "EMCON", "XNET", "CHAOS", "UDP", "mux"};

    public void receivePacket(Packet packet) {
        System.out.println(packet + "\n");
        System.out.println("this is packet " + i + " :" + "\n");
        i++;

        IPPacket tpt=(IPPacket)packet;
        if (packet != null) {

            int ppp=tpt.protocol;
            String proto=protocoll[ppp];
            System.out.println("about the ip packet in network layer : \n");

            System.out.println("******************************************************************");
                if(tpt.dont_frag){
                    System.out.println("dft bi is set. packet will not be fragmented \n");

                }else{
                    System.out.println("dft bi is not set. packet will  be fragmented \n");
                }
                System.out.println(" \n destination ip is :"+tpt.dst_ip);
                System.out.println("\n this is source ip :"+tpt.src_ip);
                System.out.println("\n this is hop limit :"+tpt.hop_limit);
                System.out.println(" \n this is identification field  :"+tpt.ident);
                System.out.println(" \npacket length :"+tpt.length);
                System.out.println("\n packet priority  :"+(int)tpt.priority);
                System.out.println("type of service field"+tpt.rsv_tos);
                if(tpt.r_flag){
                    System.out.println("releiable transmission");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("not reliable");
                }
                System.out.println("protocol version is : "+(int)tpt.version);
                System.out.println("flow label field"+tpt.flow_label);

                System.out.println("**********************************************************************");

                System.out.println("datalink lavel analysis");
                System.out.println("********************************************************************");
                 DatalinkPacket dp = packet.datalink;


                 EthernetPacket ept=(EthernetPacket)dp;
                 System.out.println("this is destination mac address :"+ept.getDestinationAddress());
                 System.out.println("\n this is source mac address"+ept.getSourceAddress());



                System.out.println("*********************************************************************");
                System.out.println("this is about type of packet");
                System.out.println("******************************************************************************");

                if (proto.equals(("TCP"))) {
                    System.out.println(" /n this is TCP packet");
                    TCPPacket tp = (TCPPacket) packet;
                    System.out.println("this is destination port of tcp :" + tp.dst_port);
                    if (tp.ack) {
                        System.out.println("\n" + "this is an acknowledgement");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("this is not an acknowledgment packet");
                    }

                    if (tp.rst) {
                        System.out.println("reset connection ");
                    }
                    System.out.println(" \n protocol version is :" + tp.version);
                    System.out.println("\n this is destination ip " + tp.dst_ip);
                    System.out.println("this is source ip"+tp.src_ip);
                    if(tp.fin){
                       System.out.println("sender does not have more data to transfer");
                    }
                    if(tp.syn){
                        System.out.println("\n request for connection");
                    }

                } else if(proto.equals("ICMP")){
                    ICMPPacket ipc=(ICMPPacket)packet;
             // java.net.InetAddress[] routers=ipc.router_ip;
              //for(int t=0;t
                //  System.out.println("\n"+routers[t]);
             // }
              System.out.println(" \n this is alive time :"+ipc.alive_time);
              System.out.println("\n number of advertised address :"+(int)ipc.addr_num);
              System.out.println("mtu of the packet is :"+(int)ipc.mtu);
              System.out.println("subnet mask :"+ipc.subnetmask);
              System.out.println("\n source ip :"+ipc.src_ip);
              System.out.println("\n destination ip:"+ipc.dst_ip);
              System.out.println("\n check sum :"+ipc.checksum);
              System.out.println("\n icmp type :"+ipc.type);
              System.out.println("");


            } else if(proto.equals("UDP")){
                    UDPPacket pac=(UDPPacket)packet;
                    System.out.println("this is udp packet \n");
                    System.out.println("this is source port :"+pac.src_port);
                    System.out.println("this is destination port :"+pac.dst_port);

            }

            System.out.println("******************************************************");

            }




        }




    public static void main(String str[]) throws Exception {
        NetworkInterface[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
        boolean lt;



        for (int i = 0; i <devices.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " :" + devices[i].name + "(" + devices[i].description + ")");
            System.out.println("    data link:" + devices[i].datalink_name + "("
                    + devices[i].datalink_description + ")");

            System.out.println();
            for (NetworkInterfaceAddress a : devices[i].addresses) {
                System.out.println("    address:" + a.address + " " + a.subnet + " "
                        + a.broadcast);
            }
        }

        JpcapCaptor jpcap = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(devices[0], 2000, true, 20);

        jpcap.loopPacket(-1, new Te());
    }
}
```

My Netbeans gui for the sniffer is this.
[Capture GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSNta.png)

I use a Combox to list the devices and use a buttion to capture the packets from the device andshow it in a table.
The problem arises here . To capture the packet infinetely

```
        JpcapCaptor jpcap = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(devices[indexfromcombox], 2000, true, 20);

        jpcap.loopPacket(-1, new Te());
```

Now Te is a class that implements PacketReceiver. In my Netbeans gui First itself as the control goes to the frame . How can i can a new class from the frame which will implement my Packetreceiver function and display it in a table. From terminal it was easy as Te is the only class invloved and from main i could call Te. But in Netbeans as the main will set the Frame to be visible first. The whole control goes to the frame and i am not able to call a call loopPacket function

```
jpcap.loopPacket(-1, new {A class which would let me capture the packet on the device selcetd}());
```

How can i call another class from the JFrame.java code itself to make this possible.

I hope you understood my problem and will assist me. I am in dire need of help as this is my project and cannot show the o/p in terminal .
Thanks

Comment: Remember, Swing is single threaded, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution.

Comment: As to your basic question, you create an instance of the class you want to interact with and call it's methods, just like do you normally do

Comment: I'd also have a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)